# Using Atom to run C programs

Tags: editor, atom-editor

Almost very time I Run a program in atom, it opens 2 Consoles.
The first when I click Enter and disappears, then I can use the second properly, but I want to know why it happens. 
Thank you

Comment: And solve the "error" of course !!

Comment: this is not related to C.

Comment: What does this have to do with C? What extension are you using to run the program?